# AutoHotKey - one keypress for two different things?

Tags: autohotkey

I want a key to send a text to chat. but when that game window isn't active/doesn't exist I just want it to work like normal. For instance, the arrow keys. I want to use them for chat macros, but outside the game or if it's not running I want the arrow keys to work as intended, left/right/up down.

Comment: I looked through the suggestions but couldn't really find what I was looking for because I probably read through them too fast.
but thanks for the help. I found a solution to my question.

Comment: I don't know how neither of them could help. They're both about exactly what you're asking: making hot keys work one way when a specific program is running, and the standard way when it isn't. Oh, well. Glad you found a solution. You should either post it here as an answer to help others, or delete your question so that people don't spend time answering it when you don't need the help any longer.

Comment: You're looking for [#IfWinActive](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm).

Comment: Ken: I never said they didn't help. I was just stating that I was reading through the suggestion to quick to see the one you linked in your response. that's why I missed it. you misunderstood me.


and here is what I used for it to work as I wanted. for the game only and work normally when game isn't active.

http://pastebin.com/9XawpKQE